# Errors typing props using interface in Vue 3 (Vue: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-props

I want to type props using an interface, this is my code and works correctly.
But:

```
defineProps<Props>();
```

Is highlighted with this error (Vue: Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Client } from "@/clients/interfaces/client.interface";

interface Props {
  clients: Client[];
}

const props = defineProps<Props>();
</script>
```

Reading and searching i tryed to configure .eslintrc with

```
  env: {
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true
  }
```

and installing     "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0"

I'm using webStorm, i don't know if it's relevant.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html), the syntax used in the problem description is correct, but ESLint doesn't like it.

Solution I implemented:
One of the other options in the documentation, e.g. from code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Book {
  title: string
  author: string
  year: number
}

const props = defineProps<{
  book: Book
}>()
</script>
```

This way, I don't get the ESLint error, I can declare the prop type with the corresponding interface and without the verbosity of declaring each prop with its type and require, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the IDE settings pointed to wrong Typescript.
Just ensure that the TypeScript setting of the IDE points to the correct version:

[image: PHPStorm Settings]